# Arcpy: Describing spatial reference system

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I am writing the following code to make a report describing a feature class. SO far, I got their names and shape type, but now I need to get SRS/coordinate system for each of the feature class. 
I think I can use

```
spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(dataset).spatialReference
```

but what would the parameter be if I use this in my code?

```
def data_report(workspace):

elements = defaultdict(list)

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, topdown=True)

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for dirname in dirnames:  # 'FeatureDataset'
        desc = arcpy.da.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, dirname))
        elements[desc['dataType']].append(desc)

    for filename in filenames:
        desc = arcpy.da.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
        elements[desc['dataType']].append(desc)

report = []

for element_type, element_list in elements.items():
    report += [f"{element_type}:"]
    for element_description in element_list:

        if element_type == "FeatureClass":
            report +=  [f"\t\t{element_description['baseName']}"] # Here I just output the path, but there's lots more info in the Describe object
            report +=  [f"\t\t\tShape type is: {element_description['shapeType']}"]
```

Comment: One possible solution is that I can use List function to make a list of the feature class, but is there any way I can do that without making the list?

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question (Edit the Question instead). The DA Describe returns a dictionary; compiling a list of dictionaries (or feature classes) doesn't seem to be getting you closer to your goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are simply asking how to get a string (text) representation of your `spatial_ref` spatial reference object that you can append to your report...

Here is the [documentation for the spatial reference class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/spatialreference.htm).  If you examine the **Properties** section, you will find various properties that return a string (text).  Eg, **"name"**.  You can use one of these, or join several of them together if you need more information about the spatial reference.

Eg,

```
spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(dataset).spatialReference
spatialRefName = spatial_ref.name
```

or simply:

```
spatialRefName = arcpy.Describe(dataset).spatialReference.name
```

Comment: Sorry I meant what should I put into (dataset) ? I already have desc = arcpy.da.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)), so should I use (os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)) again?

Comment: report += [f"\t\t\t{} has an unknown spatial reference".format(fc)]
              ^
SyntaxError: f-string: empty expression not allowed

Comment: This is how I tried to do in in report +=, but I got the error message

Comment: You are mixing f-strings and format() strings.  It should be either `[f"\t\t\t{fc} has an unknown spatial reference"]` (with `f` prefix and variable in `{}`) OR `["\t\t\t{} has an unknown spatial reference".format(fc)]` (without `f` prefix and variable in `format()`).  They are two different and incompatible ways of interpolating/formatting variable values into literal strings.